# NuSoap Server Works with SoapUI, but not C#.NET 3.5

Tags: c#, php, codeigniter, soap, nusoap

I'm setting up a web service to accept orders from a third party, and I've been having some troubles some odd errors. I'm running CodeIgniter with a NuSoap server handling the request. They're running C# .NET 3.5 to send the request. Every time they submit the request through their app, it returns an error: "Object Reference not set to an Instance of an object."

I asked them to send me the SOAP request and response, and here they are (unfortunately it's proprietary, so I can't provide all the info and I've changed some names)

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
  <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://InspectionService/SendInspectionRequestTPA</Action> 
   <h:AuthenticateHeader xmlns="http://InspectionService/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:h="http://InspectionService/">
   <UserName>USERNAME</UserName> 
   <Password>PASSWORD</Password> 
  </h:AuthenticateHeader>
  </s:Header>
 <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <SendInspectionRequestTPA xmlns="http://InspectionService/">
  <RequesterName>Bob</RequesterName> 
  <RequesterExt>5555555555</RequesterExt> 
  <RequesterEmail>email@test.net</RequesterEmail> 
  <SaleDate>2013-08-04T00:00:00</SaleDate> 
  <VehicleYear>2010</VehicleYear> 
  <VehicleMake>MITSUBISHI</VehicleMake> 
  <VehicleModel>GALANT ES/SE</VehicleModel>
  <Mileage>60000</Mileage> 
  <VIN>12341234123412341</VIN> 
  <ContractNumber>SEP00001025NVSC</ContractNumber> 
  <ClaimNumber>C000001061</ClaimNumber> 
  <InspectionType>Automotive</InspectionType> 
  <InspectionReason>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">RIGHT FRONT WINDOW IS NOT WORKING</anyType> 
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">MOTOR SHORTED</anyType> 
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">REPLACE RIGHT FRONT WINDOW MOTOR</anyType> 
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">THIS IS A TEST INSPECTION.</anyType> 
  </InspectionReason>
  <RepairSite>CLAIM DEMO DEALER-SEP 2</RepairSite> 
  <Address1>ADDR</Address1> 
  <Address2 /> 
  <City>OMAHA</City> 
  <State>NE</State> 
  <Zip>68144</Zip> 
  <Contact>JOE SERVICER</Contact>
  </SendInspectionRequestTPA>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

(Note that I removed some sensitive lines in the request and changed others)
And the response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header /> 
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>... stream ...</SOAP-ENV:Body> 
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

(Edit: This was part of our issue, in that this debug response was truncated by the company--so we never got the actual debug info from their side)

The thing here is that this request works perfectly (read: as expected) when submitted through SOAPUI. Here's the code from my CodeIgniter Controller:

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Carwash extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors','Off');
    $ns = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/carwash';
    $ep = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/carwash';
    $this->ns = $ns;
    $this->load->library("Nusoap_library"); // load nusoap toolkit library in controller
    $this->nusoap_server = new soap_server(); // create soap server object
    $this->nusoap_server->configureWSDL("EACCarwash", $this->ns, $ep); //, "rpc", 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http', array(),); // wsdl configuration
    $this->nusoap_server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $ns; // server namespace
    $this->nusoap_server->namespaces['soap'] ='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/';
    $this->load->model('carwash_model');
  }

  public function index()
   {
    $fi_input = array(
   "RequesterName" => "xsd:string",
   "RequesterExt" => "xsd:string",
   "RequesterEmail" => "xsd:string",
   "ContractHolder" => "xsd:string",
   "SaleDate" => "xsd:dateTime",
   "SaleOdometer" => "xsd:string",
   "VehicleYear" => "xsd:string",
   "VehicleMake" => "xsd:string",
   "VehicleModel" => "xsd:string",
   "Mileage" => "xsd:string",
   "VIN" => "xsd:string",
   "ContractNumber" => "xsd:string",
   "ClaimNumber" => "xsd:string",
   "InspectionType" => "xsd:string",
      "InspectionReason" => "xsd:struct",
      "RepairSite" => "xsd:string",
      "Address1" => "xsd:string",
      "Address2" => "xsd:string",
      "City" => "xsd:string",
      "State" => "xsd:string",
      "Zip" => "xsd:string",
      "Phone" => "xsd:string",
      "Contact" => "xsd:string",
      "TpaCode" => "xsd:string"
    );
    $fi_return = array(
      "SendInspectionRequestTPAResult" => "xsd:string"
     );
     $this->nusoap_server->register('SendInspectionRequestTPA',
      $fi_input,
      $fi_return,
      "urn:SOAPServerWSDL",
      "urn:".$this->ns."/SendInspectionRequestTPA",
      "rpc",
      "encoded",
      "DESCRIPTION HERE",
      "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");

    function SendInspectionRequestTPA($req_name, $req_ext, $req_email, $contract_holder, $sale_date, $sale_odometer, $v_year, $v_make, $v_model, $mileage, $vin, $contract_no, $claim_no, $insp_type, $insp_reason, $repair_site, $addr1, $addr2, $city, $state, $zip, $phone, $contact_name, $tpa_code)
    {
      $CI =& get_instance();
      if($CI->check_creds() == FALSE)
      {
        return new soap_fault('Client','','Not authorized');
      }
      else
      {
        if(!$req_name){ return new soap_fault('Client','','Requester Name Required');}
        if(!$sale_date){ return new soap_fault('Client','','Sale Date Required');}
        if(!$v_year){ return new soap_fault('Client','','Vehicle Year Required');}
        if(!$v_make){ return new soap_fault('Client','','Vehicle Make Required');}
        if(!$v_model){ return new soap_fault('Client','','Vehicle Model Required');}
        if(!$mileage){ return new soap_fault('Client','','Mileage Required');}
        if(!$contract_no){ return new soap_fault('Client','','Contract Number Required');}
        if(!$claim_no){ return new soap_fault('Client','','Claim Number Required');}
        if(!$insp_type){ return new soap_fault('Client','','Inspection Type Required');}
        if(!$insp_reason){ return new soap_fault('Client','','Inspection Reason Required');}
        if(!$repair_site){ return new soap_fault('Client','','Repair Site Required');}
        if(!$contact_name){ return new soap_fault('Client','','Contact Required');}
        if(!$tpa_code){ return new soap_fault('Client','','TPA Code Required');}

        $id = $CI->carwash_model->add_fni_insp($req_name, $req_ext, $req_email, $contract_holder, $sale_date, $sale_odometer, $v_year, $v_make, $v_model, $mileage, $vin, $contract_no, $claim_no, $insp_type, $insp_reason, $repair_site, $addr1, $addr2, $city, $state, $zip, $phone, $contact_name, $tpa_code) or die(new soap_fault('Server','','Error Processing Request'));
        return (string) ((int) $id);
        //else{return new soap_fault('Server', '','Error processing request');}
      }
    }

    $this->soapy = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $this->nusoap_server->service($this->soapy);
  }

  public function hookTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/i";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
  }

  public function check_creds()
  {
    if(isset($this->soapy))
    {
      $sUsername = $this->hookTextBetweenTags($this->soapy, 'Username');
      $sPassword = $this->hookTextBetweenTags($this->soapy, 'Password');
      $verify = $this->carwash_model->check_fni_user($sUsername, $sPassword);
      //var_dump($verify);
      return $verify;
    }
  }

}//end class
```

I will confess that I'm relatively new with setting up SOAP Servers, so if something's really stupid or out of place, I would really love to hear about that, too.

When I googled the "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" error, it seems that essentially the server was expecting an object and didn't get one. The only place that would happen is the "inspectionreason" field, which is well-formed in their request. That's pretty much the only thing that I could pinpoint as to where that error comes from. But since it works with SOAPUI, I'm inclined to think that the error is related to the request--and not the server.

Does anyone see any glaring errors? Or is there something with NuSoap that I should be configuring?

Let me know if I can provide any more details. Thanks!

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I have the same problem with FIAS SendInspectionRequestTPA - "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object". Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't fix this. We called in the big guns and partnered with another company who already had something established. Basically the problem "Object Reference not set of an instance of an object" is that FIAS is actually sending an object of an array of objects encoded as strings (or something like that). In PHP, that's a LOT Of casting, and with a SOAP server expecting a specific type, I never quite figured out what was the top level of object/string/array or what. In plain terms, they send a request which does not meet the criteria from their implementation docs.

Comment: Resolved - I just add empty <SOAP-ENV:Header/> and it worked, FIAS confirm that response is ok. Weird.